# rdiff-backup Warning: Metadata file has no digest for file

Tags: backup, rdiff-backup, metadata

I'm trying to verify my rdiff-backup, but it seems like half of the files are missing their metadata hash. This means I get tons of errors when running the `--compare-hash` function:

```
Warning: Metadata file has no digest for Distros/Linux/linuxmint-17.3-cinnamon-64bit.iso, unable to compare.
```

similarly the `--verify` function produces tons of errors:

```
Warning: Cannot find SHA1 digest for file linuxmint-19.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso,
perhaps because this feature was added in v1.1.1
```

My rdiff-backup version is 2.05 so I don't understand why it's missing all of these SHA1 hashes. Is there anyway to regenerate these hashes without doing the whole backup over again?

Answer (score 0):

I looked all over the internet for threads with the same error complaining about missing SHA1 sums, but no one ever seemed to have any solutions. Therefore, I decided to look at the metadata files manually and write a script to simply "fill in" the entries that had missing SHA1 sums.

You can run the script by tying `fix_metadata.py <your backup directory>` - The original metadata file is backed up, but so far in my testing, this seems to fix the problem. I would still like to know why so many files had missing checksums to begin with.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Usage: fix_metadata.py <backup folder>

import re, gzip, hashlib, os, time, sys

def digest(filename, chunk=1024**2):
    #Compute sha1 digest
    h = hashlib.sha1()
    print("Calculating hash of:", filename, end='')
    count = 0
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(chunk)
            if data:
                h.update(data)
                count += 1
                if not count % 100:
                    print('.', end='', flush=True)
            else:
                print()
                return h.hexdigest()


os.chdir(sys.argv[1])
for meta in os.listdir('rdiff-backup-data'):
    if 'metadata' in meta and meta.endswith('.gz'):
        meta = os.path.join('rdiff-backup-data', meta)
        fixed = meta+'.fixed'
        print("Processing:", meta)
        output = gzip.open(fixed, 'w')
    else:
        continue
    
    entry = []      #Entry for a single file
    sha1 = False    #Did we find a SHA1 hash?
    updated = 0     #Number of entries updated
    with gzip.open(meta, 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('File '):
                if entry and not sha1:
                    filename = (re.sub('^File','', entry[0])).strip()
                    if os.path.exists(filename):
                        if os.path.isfile(filename):
                            entry.insert(3, '  SHA1Digest ' + digest(filename.strip())+'\n')
                            updated += 1
                    else:
                        print("Could not find file:", filename)
                output.write(''.join(entry).encode())
                entry = []      
                sha1 = False
            if line.startswith('  SHA1Digest'):
                sha1 = True
            entry.append(line)
        if entry:
            output.write(''.join(entry).encode())
        output.close()
    if updated:
        print(updated, "files fixed")
        os.rename(meta, meta + '.'+str(int(time.time())) + '.original.bak')
        os.rename(fixed, meta)
        print('Finished:', meta)
    else:
        os.remove(fixed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried to fix it with your script.

Because my backup has 200GB and is done twice a day, there are a lot of meta-files to update. Because this takes a long time I could think a bit about the script. It certainly creates hashes for all the files, where they are missing. But it creates always the hash of the current version of the file. So I updated the file, to compare the modTime before creating a hash for it. But what with the files, that do not have a hash and the modTime does not match. I don't have a solution for those.

The script probably fixes the symptoms but not the problem, coming up with hashes of current files also for the old versions of the files.

Because the hashes get propagated thru the meta-files, also if they are missing, on can check, when the hashes disappear with a statement like this:

```
zgrep -c  SHA1Digest BACKUP_DIR/rdiff-backup-data/*meta*snapshot.gz
```

When the count drops, there the hashes went missing. I didn't find the reason for the disappearing hashes, but it has probably to do with a failed backup run. One fix, for the problem of generating wrong hashes for changed files, would be, to propagating the hashes from the old meta-files to the new ones, as long as the modTime stays the same. This in hope, that a file-change/new-modTime would result with an new hash in a new meta-file.

It would be an improvement, if rdiff-backup would fix missing hashes as part of a backup run, as long as the correct version of the files are still at hand.

So I ended up copying the "corrupt" backup away and making a new fresh one. The "corrupt" backup can still be used to restore even without the hashes, but it generates a lot of warnings. Because I make a nightly restore, I did not want these warnings about the missing hashes. I also suspect, that the restore is slower without the hashes, but I did not verify this.